# How can you Join multiple tables in a DataSet C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I've converted an xml document into a DataSet with DataTables containing relational infomation.

I need to merge the tables into a single table exploiting the relational information is there a way to Do SQL like queries on a Dataset to get a dataTable which can be subsequently used to populate a datagrid?

Comment: there is an example: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us) I hope that will help you. If not, there is another (more complicated) example: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the DataRelation class.

I wont repeat all the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation(vs.71).aspx) docs.